# Cannot logout ever when user has offline_access granted

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, facebook-php-sdk

I am currently facing an issue with the PHP SDK's getLogoutURL function. The function dont seem to work when the user has offline_access granted.

There is a bug that is already raised on facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/250825644953332?browse=search_4eda7219406225a11006685

Has someone been able to temporarily fix this issue? Could someone help me on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abishek, try using javascript sdk to logout for now. 
i believe we need to search for a bug or post a bug on this.  I will do when i have more time.

We can follow with the bug report here, once found or posted.

---

> Abishek Srikaanth Hey Shawn. Appreciate your help... There is a bug
>   already on FB Support
>   https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/250825644953332?browse=search_4eda8228b8f722c69411727.
>   I additionally wanted to check if someone can help me on stackoverflow
>   as well.